# Running each child form as a separate thread in a MDI container

Tags: c#, winforms, multithreading, mdi

Is it possible to run each child form of a MDI form on a separate thread? If so, can you please give some codes and example how to setup this?

Thanks!

Comment: This does not make sense - `Run form from a separate thread`, perhaps you want to run a method in a separate thread?

Comment: Don't attempt this. Maintain a one to one mapping between users and user interface threads.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I can't tell from the question wether you are aware of the exotic nature of the solution you are proposing. I apologize if this answer completely misses the mark.

I assume that you want *responsiveness* in your application. That you don't want other forms to "hang" while one form is doing work.

However, having a different GUI thread per form is **not** how one usually achieves this. I don't know if it is even possible.

You will still have only one thread handling all the graphics (aka "the GUI Thread"), but all time consuming work should be immediately offloaded to another thread (aka worker thread). That way the app remains responsive.

I suggest you check out this video. Applicable or not, within 4-6 minutes, you should know wether this is the answer you are looking for.

[DNRTV episode with Stephen Toub](http://www.dnrtv.com/default.aspx?showNum=188)

Another possibility is that you are asking about how to display a form without it being [modal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2834799/winforms-programming-modal-and-non-modal-forms-problem).

Comment: It IS possible, I've done it before, I'm just searching to find the code sample I used a few years ago, there were some really neat tricks for it.

Answer (score 3):

No.

Any GUI activity has to happen on the main thread.

Processing can be done in a separate thread, in which case, try using the `BackgroundWorker` in your child forms.

Answer (score 1):

This [MSDN forum post](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/3f0e7794-8671-47c4-aa9a-3bd1f85c9963/) says that forms can be run in separate threads. I don't know if it's applicable to child MDI forms, though.  But the technique is simple enough:

```
Thread thread = new Thread( () =>
   {
         var yourForm = new YourForm();
         Application.Run(yourForm);
   });
thread.ApartmentState = ApartmentState.STA;
thread.Start();
```

Comment: no, it is not possible. As you have to set "MdiParent=this" somewhere and this will try to get an element from another thread.