# C# Can I create Controls in another thread?

Tags: c#, user-interface

Normally controls are created at the main thread.
Is it possible to create some of the child controls in another thread?

Comment: .NET 2.0 onwards will in fact prevent you from doing this.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7915795/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

tl,dr **Don't do it**.

The controls can be created on a different thread, *however*, when they are added to the parent (created on a different thread), <del>then there will likely be</del> a cross-thread exception raised. I am not sure if this exception is "guaranteed", but **don't do it**. (There are cross-thread exceptions instead of implicit marshaling *for a reason*; better to die fast than deadlock later.)

Cross-threading and [winform] controls don't mix. Of course, if different forms are on different threads, and each form's children are on the same thread as the form, and cross-thread access is guarded or used via "invoke" or similar ... but a form isn't a "child" control.

Happy coding.

---

Sample cross-thread exception message:

> System.InvalidOperationException: Cross-thread operation not valid: Control '...' accessed from a thread other than the thread it was created on.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure why you would want to do this. What I would do is call back to a method on the main thread using a delegate and add the controls there.

Answer (score 0):

Controls, no. [Forms, yes.](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/3f0e7794-8671-47c4-aa9a-3bd1f85c9963/)

```
Thread thread = new Thread( () =>
   {
         var yourForm = new YourForm();
         Application.Run(yourForm);
   });
thread.ApartmentState = ApartmentState.STA;
thread.Start();
```